# Childbrowser plugin for phonegap opens ios embedded webview and childbrowser too

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a problem with the ios phonegap plugin childbrowser,

I disabled the link:

`<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" onclick="return false;">foo</a>`

On android i have no problems, but ios opens its embedded webview in background, too.

What can I do to avoid to open the ios webview?

I am using sencha touch 1.1.1 and phonegap 1.4.1

Comment: If you don't have any problems in Android, why only tag it as an Android question?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have the `stay-in-webview` parameter set to `true` in your 'config.xml'. It's an iOS specific parameter.

> Open all links in WebView
>
> stay-in-webview with values true or false
>
> -example: `<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />`
>
> -if set to true, all links (even with target set to blank) will open in the app's webview
>
> -only use this preference if you want pages from your server to take over your entire app
>
> -default is false

(Source: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml)